# Google maps places autocomplete loading events

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm using the [Google Maps Places Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) api.

I would like to show an Ajax spinner during the search, before the autocomplete dropdown is displayed.

How can I determine when the places results are ready? Is there some event fired off?

This is particularly helpful on bad internet connections since the latency can sometimes be up to 5 seconds. The user needs to know the search box is an autocomplete inputbox before frantically pressing enter to search.

Comment: Have you tried writing your own control rather than the auto complete just use the geocoder service? on key up (say after a second do a geocode, show your spinner, then on geocode complete hide the spinner and show a list with some result options.

Comment: @loanburger I did try, with the autocomplete its a bit leaner since only 1 http call would be made per query and selected item. If you use the api's google has made public it takes more than a single call to replicate what the api offers (including the coordinates & information about what you select). Google also wont block your requests as much.

Comment: Hey, pressing Enter to search is also a valid operation, if Google Maps lets us do it, why shouldn't you let your users do it? Look at this demo, it also does it: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/

Answer (score 3):

You could use the *autocomplete service* to get the query predictions. It has a callback function.

On the example from the link you provided, you could declare *input* as a global variable in the script. And access it with the *autocomplete service* after the *initialize* function:

```
var input;
function initialize () {
  ...
  input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  ...
}

function showSpinner() {
  document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = 'block';

  var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
  service.getQueryPredictions({ input: input }, callback);
}

function callback(predictions, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = 'none';
    return;
  }
}
```

As for the changes in the html document:

```
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a location" onkeypress="showSpinner()">
    <img id="spinner" src="spinner.gif" style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0; width: 250px; display: none">
  </body>
```

I would run this only if a one-second timeout (i.e. if the user's internet connection is slow), otherwise the spinner looks like a subliminal image.